# Screen recording

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator

В новом эммуляторе появился screen recording, только не очень еще понял как его запустить так, чтоб записать нужную картинку(scene форму) мне экран в (с помощью camera feeling), вместо летающего зеленого квадрата, который появялется когда активируешь камеру.